# Case insensitive search of elements of NSDictionary in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary, swift-extensions

It is possible to do a caseinsensitive search of keys in a Swift Dictionary in Swift using:

```
extension Dictionary where Key == String {
    func valueForKeyInsensitive<T>(key: Key) -> T? {
        let foundKey = self.keys.first { $0.compare(key, options: .caseInsensitive) == .orderedSame } ?? key
        return self[foundKey] as? T
    }
}
```

However, when I try to do something similar to extend NSDictionary, the compiler gives error

```
 'Trailing 'where' clause for extension of non-generic type 'NSDictionary':

extension NSDictionary where Key == String {
...

}
```

How can I do a case insensitive search of keys in an NSDictionary?

Comment: `NSDictionary` isn't generic. You only know that the keys are `NSObject`s, nothing else.

Comment: I also wouldn't advise using that first method. It's doing a linear search of the keys, which pretty much entirely defeats the purpose of `Dictionary`.

Comment: How would you do the first search?

Comment: I would lowercase values before inserting them in the dictionary, and then lookup by the lowercase values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NSDictionary case insensitive objectForKey:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607343/nsdictionary-case-insensitive-objectforkey)

Comment: That's a really good question with good answers.. My question was slightly different--about the difference between a Swift Dictionary and an NSDictionary, however, the link provides useful related discussion. Thanks!